# Extended Service Set in Wireless Networks

Tags: wireless

I am learning about the different kinds of service sets in Wireless networks and I have a few questions about the ESS.

[image]

If the BSSs had the same settings but different SSIDs, would this still be considered an ESS and would roaming be still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wireless client needs to authenticate and associate with an SSID. If SSIDs change while roaming that association needs to repeat, making *seamless* roaming impossible. Of course, clients can roam with some interruption in connectivity.

Comment: Just as a thing worth considering: It's right in the name. SSID, Service Set Identifier. Extended Service Set Identifier encapsulates multiple instances of the same Service Set Identifier. If you change the SSID, the client no longer expects to connect to the same network. Imagine if you owned 2 locations of a hamburger franchise and called one Fancy Burger and one Stinky Burger. Why would you go to Stinky Burger if you want a Fancy Burger? You name them the same so the client recognizes them and knows what to expect.